# Добавление данных в таблицу Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Возникла проблема, не добавляются данные во вторую таблицу. Ошибку найти никак не могу.
DBhelper. Здесь не добавляет в InsertNew

```
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String summ1 = "summ";
public static final String date1 = "date";
public static final String time1 = "time";
public static final String category1 = "category";
public static final String account1 = "account";
public static final String comment1 = "comment";

public static final String table2 = "cons";

public static final String KEY_ID2 = "_id2";
public static final String summ2 = "summa";
public static final String date2 = "data";
public static final String time2 = "time";
public static final String category2 = "categor";
public static final String account2 = "accounts";
public static final String comment2 = "comments";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + add_summ + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + summ1 + " REAL NOT NULL," + date1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            time1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            category1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            account1 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + comment1 + " text" + ");");

    db.execSQL("create table " + table2 + "(" + KEY_ID2
            + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + summ2 + " REAL NOT NULL," + date2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            time2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            category2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            account2 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + comment2 + " text" + ");");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + add_summ);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + table2);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String sum,String date,String time, String categ, String acc, String comm) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(summ1,sum);
    contentValues.put(date1,date);
    contentValues.put(time1,time);
    contentValues.put(category1,categ);
    contentValues.put(account1,acc);
    contentValues.put(comment1,comm);
    long result = db.insert(add_summ,null ,contentValues);
   /* if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;*/
   return true;
}

public long insertNew(String a,String b,String c, String d, String f, String g) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(summ2,a);
    content.put(date2,b);
    content.put(time2,c);
    content.put(category2,d);
    content.put(account2,f);
    content.put(comment2,g);
    return db.insert(table2,null ,content);

}
```

Вот вызов функции InsertNew

```
   DBHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private EditText sum;
private EditText category;
private EditText acc;
private EditText comment;
private EditText data;
private EditText time;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_rashod);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    //Находим кнопки
    sum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rashod);
    category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.categoria);
    acc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.schet);
    comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comm);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
    time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vremya);
}

public void onClick(View a) {

    dbHelper.insertNew(sum.getText().toString(),
            data.getText().toString(),
            time.getText().toString(),
            category.getText().toString(),
            acc.getText().toString(),
            comment.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

Comment: Непосредственно перед вызовом: 1. Убедиться что db в порядке 2. Убедиться что table2 существует

Comment: 1. Да, все с ним в порядке. 2. Да, таблица существует, а данные так и не добавляются